# php and problem with "title" tags

Tags: php, html, title

I have a multi language site. Structure of my site is like this:

```
/index.php
----/en/login.php
----/some other language/login.php
```

At index page, user choose his language, language is saved in cookie. From login page user can go back to index and change his language. Now, that's the root of my problem:

When user, at "login" page clicks "change language", he is directed to "deleteLangCookie.php". That php is simple, looks like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE['lang']))
    setcookie("lang", "", time()-60*60*24*100, "/");
header('Location: ../index.php');
?>
```

As you can see - 5 lines, pure php. Now, for some time Google webmaster tools complains that "deleteLangCookie.php" HAS THE SAME TITLE as "index.php". How's that? "deletelangunage" is not included in "index.php", it's just "a gate" to "index.php" when user clicks "change language button".

"DeleteLangCookie.php" IS NOT indexed, it's removed from cache and disallowed by robots!

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is not indexed, it is not a problem. The duplicate titles is only to help you, not a penalty by google.

Maybe try this:
Add a 301 to your header. That way you're saying "this is not a real url", and google might skip the page alltogether. The "deleteLangCookie.php" url is not a "real" url to land on anyway: it does something, but then always redirects you to another place.

```
    Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
    Header( "Location: {$uri}" );
```

Comment: how to change my header so it includes "301"?

Comment: No prob, don't hesitate to accept the answer if it works for your problem ;)

Comment: well, no, it won't do! :\ header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
header('Location: ../index.php'); will just bring me back to previous location instead of index.php (exact version you wrote won't do either)

Comment: the $uri in there must be changed to your own url ofcourse :). the header I'm calling is exactly the same as your own. So if `header('Location: ../index.php');` worked for you, my version (first the 301 header, then the location) should do the same?

Comment: Yes, yes i have replaced "$url". Now it works - i just had to restart my browser. There was probbably some problem with cache or something like that...